# Sending multipart email in java

Tags: java, email, mime-message

This is my code:

```
            MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

            emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,  new InternetAddress(to));      
            emailMessage.setSubject("testing html and inline images emails");

            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

            BodyPart text = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><br/> <p align=center><img src=\"cid:senny\"> </p>";
            text.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(text);

            BodyPart image = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("http://mobilemarketingwatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Is-Google-Searching-for-the-Next-Big-Thing1.jpg");         
            image.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            image.addHeader("Content-ID","<senny>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(image);

            emailMessage.setContent(multipart, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            emailMessage.saveChanges();            

            Transport.send(emailMessage);
```

I am getting in the email this message:

> javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@598f069a

instead of the real message.
 Any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

The method for [sending a Multipart object](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setContent%28javax.mail.Multipart%29) is `emailMessage.setContent(multipart)`, not `setContent(Object o, String type)`